# ipython notebook terminals unavailable

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I installed anaconda and I get this
(python 2.7.9)

[image]

I am running ipython notebook on Windows 8 and terminal option unavailable for me.
 How do I activate it? please

Comment: I tried to find the solution and also installed `terminado`:  [img](http://i.imgur.com/kwHlTFO.png)

Answer (score 8):

Windows do not support tty terminal, and terminado only works if the underlying terminal is a tty. So for now there is not support for terminals on Windows. There is no short-term plan to support terminal either.

Comment: Pardon me for a basic question, but does this mean ipython notebooks cannot be used in a windows machine? I ask because I have come across a whole lot of blogs and few books that talk about using ipython notebook on windows, none of which clearly address the issue OP and I are having. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, only the in-browser terminal tab is unavaillable, which mean that you cannot use the windows command prompt from in browser. The rest works fine.

Comment: See also https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/172