# How can I activate the terminal in python notebook using Windows?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am running ipython notebook on Windows 7 and terminal is unavailable. How can I activate it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ipython notebook terminals unavailable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092823/ipython-notebook-terminals-unavailable)

Comment: Summary: you can't. Terminals are Unix only.